# Why is Popover compnenent in flowbites docs but is not found when trying to import?

Tags: reactjs, flowbite

I am using flowbite-react and trying to use the popover component. I import as shown in the documentation but get the following error:

```
export 'Popover' (imported as 'Popover') was not found in 'flowbite-react'
```

My import line:

```
//flowbite
import { Spinner, Popover } from 'flowbite-react';
```

Anyone run into this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs got deployed ahead of a release. It's not in v0.7.2.

Either wait for the next release or install the latest branch.

They are on it.

https://github.com/themesberg/flowbite-react/issues/1274